# Programmatically reset Plotly plot selections

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

Currently using plotly.js wrapped inside the react-plotly library for a web application. Plotly has a behaviour where double click events trigger a reset of the plot (specifically selections within scatter plots are reset, which is the behaviour I wish to replicate). Is there a way to programmatically trigger this double click event or else to explicitly reset the selection?

I haven't been able to locate any info in the public docs and triggering a double click event on the plot does not appear to have any effect (i.e. calling `dispatchEvent(new Event('dbclick'))`)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which plot type you're using, you can modify the `selectedpoints` attribute within the traces to reset the selection. Set it to an empty list.

https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/scatter/#scatter-selectedpoints